# In express link to static assets breaks when user visits a 404 page

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express to create a simple application. I have coded my templates using handlebars which looks like something this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="english">
    <title>{{ title }} </title>
</head>
<body>

{{{body}}}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/my.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that if a user visits a 404 page, then link to every static assets in the site breaks. The only solution I have found is to hardcode links to static files like this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/js/my.js"></script>
```

Obviously, This is not the recommended way. How you guys tackle this issue ?
I have coming from Django background, and it really provides a consistent and easy way to link static contents. Do we have something similar in express (or handlebars).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

`<script src="js/my.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="/js/my.js"></script>`

Currently, you are looking for the `my.js` file within the same folder as the current page (relative path).

For example, if your page exists at:
`http://localhost:3000/myroute/mypage`

It will look for the javascript file at 
`http://localhost:3000/myroute/js/my.js`

By changing it to `/js/my.js` it will point to the root of the site (absolute path):
`http://localhost:3000/js/my.js`

[HTML Filepaths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

[All About File Paths](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/all_about_file_paths.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, It is working great. But why it didn't work earlier ?

Comment: I updated my response with a little bit of an explanation plus a link to explain filepaths a little further.